# Syntax for 'new' in java

Tags: java, inner-classes, nested-class

Constructors of non static member classes take an extra hidden parameter which is a reference to an instance of the immediately enclosing class. There is also a syntactic extension of 'new'.

In the below code,

```
class K{
    static class Ka{
        static class Kb{
            class Kc{
                class Kd{

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Test{
    K.Ka.Kb.Kc.Kd k = new K.Ka.Kb().new Kc().new Kd();
}
```

Can you please help me understand the meaning of `Kb()` in `K.Ka.Kb().new Kc().new Kd()`? I understand that `new Kc()` is required as told in first paragraph.

Comment: only if you bothered reading [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's calling the constructor of `Kb`. It's easier to show this in three statements:

```
K.Ka.Kb x1 = new K.Ka.Kb();
K.Ka.Kb.Kc x2 = x1.new Kc(); // Pass x1 as the hidden constructor arg
K.Ka.Kb.Kd.Kd k = x2.new Kd(); // Pass x2 as the hidden constructor arg
```

Answer (score 7):

The parentheses you point out actually do not apply to `Kb` but `K.Ka.Kb`.

```
new K.Ka.Kb()
```

is creating a new instance of the `K.Ka.Kb` nested class.

Comment: Oh you mean `(new K.Ka.Kb()).new Kc().new Kd();`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `kc` and `kd` are inner class. But the idiom of saying non static member class as inner class, is it a standard jargon?

Comment: [Yes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)

Answer (score 1):

`Kb()` is the default constructor for class `Kb`. It is what relates to the first `new` of the line:

1. you are creating a new instance of `Kb` (class `K.Ka.Kb` actually ; depending on the context you may omit `K.Ka.`)
2. on which you are calling `new Kc()` for creating a new instance of `Kc`
3. on which you are calling `new Kd()` for creating a new instance of `Kd`